# Firebase v.9 deleteDoc( ) doesn't do anything nor catches any error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to React and Firebase, and I got a problem where the delete document function doesn't get called and no errors were caught. The function deleteItemHandler( ) does run, but the deleteDoc( ) doesn't. I have changed rules and make sure the imports are correct, yet it still won't work.

deleteItemHandler( ), App.jsx

```
  //? Delete item function
  const deleteItemHandler = async (id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "items", id));
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Delete Button, YourCard.jsx

```
        <button
          className="btn btn-danger ms-2"
          onClick={() => {
            // console.log(props.name)
            props.deleteItemHandler(props.id)
          }}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
```

Note update:
props passing
App.jsx to UserIdentity.jsx

```
<UserIdentity
        className="userId"
        currentUser={username}
        loginHandler={loginHandler}
        logoutHandler={logoutHandler}
        addListingHandler={addListingHandler}
        //? for YourCard
        itemsFromDB={itemsFromDB}
        deleteItemHandler={deleteItemHandler}
      />
```

UserIdentity.jsx to YourCard.jsx

```
{yourItems.map((item) => {
                        return (
                          <YourCard
                            // className="YourCard"
                            name={item.name}
                            id={item.id}
                            key={item.id}
                            deleteItemHandler={props.deleteItemHandler}
                          />
                        );
                      })}
```

Comment: what does deleteItemHandler do? there's some explanation in the docs [https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data)

Comment: oops seems like I attached the wrong function 

Comment: can we see how you pass and get the "props" ? and try without "try" "catch" method

Comment: I have tried without "try catch" and it still doesn't do anything. I also don't think it's the problem with props passing, as the deleteItemHandler( ) function does run but I'm gonna attach the props passing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out that the problem lies on `addDoc()`, which adds new document with `yc2` type while `deleteDoc()` searches documents with `mc2` type. Changed the add method to `setDoc()` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

im thinking you're not handling props correctly

```
 const App = () => {
    const deleteItemHandler = async (id) => {
        await deleteDoc(doc(db, "cities", id));
    }

 return (
     <YourCard deleteItemHandler={deleteItemHandler} id={someId}}
 )
```

child

```
  export const YourCard = ({deleteItemHandler, id}) => {
  
  return (
    <button
      className="btn btn-danger ms-2"
      onClick={() => deleteItemHandler(id)}
    >
      Delete
    </button>
  )
```